# Are these diagonal braces structural?

Tags: framing

[image]

can these be removed or replaced with something else to close up the garage?

Comment: They seem like structural ties for some reason.  Maybe wind braces since they seem only near the centre of one wall.  Replacing them will probably require a structural engineer to be certain.  Adding your general location in your question might help someone else give a idea.

Comment: Thanks! located in san francisco, ca. single family home was built in 1945. It's 2 stories and is attached to other single family homes on both sides.

Comment: They certainly are not decorative. so yes, of course they are structural. Likely for seismic loads, given location. Replacing them with something else would be a question for a qualified engineer in the area, not the internet.

Comment: Since you're densely packed, with a floor above, an engineer is an absolute no-brainer. Chances are good they'd come up with a good custom bracket to replace the knee braces.

Answer (score 1):

Since it was build in 1945 chances are they did not have the products of today for the job.

It is not cosmetic so it would be structural to keep the homes on left and right leaning to much on your home.

Today one would use products from [Simpson](https://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/thenizrcsg/C-C-2021-p271.pdf)